# How to compile c for opencv, not c++

Tags: linux, opencv, compilation

I've seen here on stack how to compile C++ for opencv but not regular C. I have a .c file that I created written in c and can't find a source online that explains how to compile this c file.

Thanks

Comment: you have Mat as a class in opencv, it's very difficult to deal with it in pure c, but it is not impossible, recommand you to do some research in using c++ library in c

Comment: @tintin Mat is provided with C++ api (~/opencv2/), data type for C api(~/opencv/) is IplImage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gcc file.c -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv\
_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_flann -lm
```

Such amount of libs can be reduced depending what do you need.